# Неправильный вывод в richTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

```
            //вывод результата
        int totalWeight = 0;
        foreach (Edge edge in MinimumSpanningTree)
        {
            totalWeight += edge.Weight;
            Console.WriteLine("Вершина {0} до вершины {1} вес является {2}", edge.Vertex1, edge.Vertex2, edge.Weight);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Загальний вес: {0}", totalWeight);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

У меня консольная программа выводит все нормально

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    foreach (Edge edge in MinimumSpanningTree)
    {
        totalWeight += edge.Weight;
        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + ("Вершина ${0} до вершины {1} вес является: {2}", edge.Vertex1, edge.Vertex2, edge.Weight) + System.Environment.NewLine;
    }
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + ("Загальний вес: {0}", totalWeight) + System.Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Но когда я переделал ее в оконный приложение, и вывожу в richTextBox, все как-то криво

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наверно потому что у консоли есть перегрузка, которая подставляет нужные данные? Используйте string.Format(), а ещё лучше гляньте в сторону интерполяции строк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать [интерполяцию строк](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated).

```cs
foreach (Edge edge in MinimumSpanningTree)
{
    totalWeight += edge.Weight;
    richTextBox1.Text += $"Вершина {edge.Vertex1} до вершины {edge.Vertex2} вес является: {edge.Weight}{Environment.NewLine}";
}
richTextBox1.Text += $"Загальний вес: {totalWeight}{Environment.NewLine}";
```

Или [string.Format()](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netcore-3.1).

```cs
foreach (Edge edge in MinimumSpanningTree)
{
    totalWeight += edge.Weight;
    richTextBox1.Text += string.Format("Вершина {0} до вершины {1} вес является {2}{3}", edge.Vertex1, edge.Vertex2, edge.Weight, Environment.NewLine);
}
richTextBox1.Text += string.Format("Загальний вес: {0}{1}", totalWeight, Environment.NewLine);
```

Второй удобнее там, где вам в строке надо повторить одно и то же значение несколько раз.

```cs
string text = string.Format("{0} {1} {0} {1} {2} {2} {0}", "раз", "еще", "много");
```